# Laravel - Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::select does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get selected columns instead of full columns.

```
$profiles= auth()->user()->profile()->where('id', $id)->select('profile.id','profile.name');
```

and my `profile()` method

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Profile::class)->get();
}
```

if i remove  the `->select('profile.id','profile.name')`, it returns full columns of `profile` table but i just want only a few columns of it. And if I add in `->select()` it gives me error of:

> BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::select does not exist. in file

Please advise to change the method call. Thank you.

Comment: There is no such method available for collection helper https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections

Comment: This is the reason you don't put `->get()` after `hasMany()` in your relationship function; you completely remove the ability to chain queries, like `select()`, `where()`, etc, since you're immediately executing the query. Double check the documentation, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships, none of the example functions use `->get()` or `->first()` after `hasOne()`, `hasMany()`, `belongsTo()`, etc, and now you know why :)

Answer (score 2):

`get()` is called before `select()`(in `profile()`) which is wrong since then you are trying to call `select()` method on fetched `Collection`. So remove `get()` from your relationship functions.

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Profile::class);
}
```

Note: Do same for `user()` if you use `get()` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by changing `->select('profile.id','profile.name')` by `->pluck('profile.id','profile.name')` ?